# Script does not work the same way in terminal than launched in a service

Tags: bash, networking, debian-jessie, systemctl, wpa

I have a script to test and make connection via Wifi. It works pretty fine for WEP and WPA2 AP when launched directly in the terminal. 
But when the script is launched via a service I get a "deauthenticating by local choice" almost instantly when connecting to WPA2 AP.

Here is the script :

```
            systemctl stop dnsmasq
            systemctl stop hostapd
            systemctl disable hostapd
            ifdown wlan0
            killall wpa-supplicant
            ifup --force wlan0=wlan_orange
            sleep 30
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

**EDIT**

I try to add a "sudo" to my ifup command but he has not shown any results.

**EDIT 2**

Long term test does not show any problems on WEP connection. I suspect that the problem may come from a network setup but I don't know where to start to look at.

**EDIT 3**

I found out that the deconnection appears after the end of the sleep. I confirmed it after several tries with different time.

Comment: Have you tried with multiple APs to check this is not related to the one you're testing your script one (as in this post https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/243280/how-to-fix-deauthentication-by-local-choice) ?

Comment: Yes, I tried with multiples APs : with different phones set in AP mode but nothing differs.